# Swift, issue assigning array to variable

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, combine

so I have this file which gets a JSON array from an api endpoint, then is supposed to assign it to an observable object variable so it can be retrieved and iterated through in a foreach loop. I'm still really new to Swift but it looks as so;

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

public struct ActivityModel: Codable {
    public let id: Int
    public let name: String
    public let activity_desc: String?
}


public struct ActivitiesModel2: Codable {
    public let location: String
    public let popular: [String:ActivityModel]
}

public struct ActivitiesModel: Codable {
    public let activities: ActivitiesModel2
}

public class ActivityFetcher: ObservableObject {
    var activities: [ActivitiesModel]()

    init(){
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://mywebsite.com/api/loadapi") else { return }

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode(ActivitiesModel.self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.activities = [decodedLists]
                    }
                    print(self.activities)
                    print(decodedLists)
                } else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

The code works fine up to the point where I try to equate self.activities to decodedLists, because while printing decodedLists returns the correct array from the JSON API, printing self.activities after I define it as equal to decodedLists only returns: "[]". Why it returns an empty array when it is clearly defined when printing decodedLists is beyond me. I tried removing the brackets, thinking maybe it's converting a dictionary to an array and failing, but I can't remove any of the brackets without returning an error.

Comment: Is this code compile successfully? Because you can't create a property like `var activities: [ActivitiesModel]()` change `:` to `=` then you should print `self.activities` in `main.async` block because this is an async work. Then you have a one element in array. Maybe this will help you to understand async works -> https://medium.com/swift2go/synchronysing-the-asynchronous-in-swift-3f91a32bfb1b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s quite simple; it just has to do with [what async means](http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/). These lines of your code execute in this order:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.activities = [decodedLists] // 2
}
print(self.activities) // 1
```

So first you read and print `self.activities`, which is empty, and then some time later you give it a value of `[decodedLists]`.